# Implementation of SNMP getbulk

Tags: delphi, snmp, indy

Is it possible to implement `GetBulk` requests using `TIdSNMP` in Delphi?

```
IdSNMP1.Query.Version:=1;    
IdSNMP1.Query.PDUType := PDUGetNextRequest;
IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(OID,'',2);
while IdSNMP1.SendQuery do
begin
  if Copy (IdSNMP1.Reply.MIBOID [0], 1, Length (OID)) <> OID then break;
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Replies: ' + IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID [0] + '  ' + IdSNMP1.Reply.Value[0]);
  IdSNMP1.Query.MIBDelete(0);
  IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID [0], '');
  IdSNMP1.Query.PDUType := PDUGetNextRequest;
end
```

As a result, I am getting a `get-response`, and I would like to realize the full `GetBulk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not taking into account that a response may contain multiple OID values.  You are only looking at the first OID of each reply.  The `Reply` property has a `ValueCount` property, you should loop through all of the values, and then send the next request using the last OID provided, eg:

```
IdSNMP1.Query.Version := 1;    
IdSNMP1.Query.PDUType := PDUGetNextRequest;
IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(OID, '', ASN1_INT);
while IdSNMP1.SendQuery do
begin
  if IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueCount = 0 then Break;
  Stop := False;
  for I := 0 to IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueCount then
  begin
    Stop := (IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID[I] <> OID) and (not TextStartsWith(IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID[I], OID+'.'));
    if Stop then Break;
    Memo1.Lines.Append('Replies: ' + IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID[I] + '  ' + IdSNMP1.Reply.Value[I]);
  end;
  if Stop then Break;
  IdSNMP1.Query.MIBDelete(0);
  IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID[IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueCount-1], '');
end
```

That being said, `TIdSNMP` primarily implements only [SNMP v1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157), however [GETBULK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416#section-4.2.3) was introduced in [SNMP v2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416).  There is a [workitem](http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/19076) to update `TIdSNMP` to support newer SNMP versions.  In the meantime, SNMP v2c messages (as opposed to v2p or v2u) are *somewhat* compatible with SNMP v1 messages, so you *might* be able to do something like the following:

```
const
  PDUGetBulkRequest = $a5;

IdSNMP1.Query.Version := 1;
IdSNMP1.Query.PDUType := PDUGetBulkRequest;
IdSNMP1.Query.ID := ...; // desired request-id value
IdSNMP1.Query.ErrorStatus := ...; // desired non-repeaters value
IdSNMP1.Query.ErrorIndex := ...; // desired max-repetitions value
IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(OID, '', ASN1_INT);
while IdSNMP1.SendQuery do
begin
  if IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueCount = 0 then Break;
  Stop := False;
  for I := 0 to IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueCount then
  begin
    Stop := (IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID[I] <> OID) and (not TextStartsWith(IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID[I], OID+'.'));
    if Stop then Break;
    Memo1.Lines.Append('Replies: ' + IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID[I] + '  ' + IdSNMP1.Reply.Value[I]);
  end;
  if Stop then Break;
  IdSNMP1.Query.MIBDelete(0);
  IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID[IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueCount-1], '');
end
```

Comment: Thank you. In your example also returns get-response. I think we need to change PDUType := PDUGetNextRequest on GetBolkreguest. This type is not provided?